# Can anyone find an image of Henry Bolingbroke's Sovereygne Feather Seal?

Tags: england, heraldry

[Henry IV of England](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_IV_of_England) used a *"remarkable seal"* with two tall feathers (around the shield, helm and crest), each entwined with a garter which had his *"favorite and significant"* motto **"SOVEREYGNE"** written on it, which he is said to have used *"a short time before his accession"*, as Duke of Lancaster. *(Sources: English Heraldry, by Ch. Boutell, pg. 242. A Complete Guide to Heraldry, by Arthur Charles Fox-Davies)*

A modern depiction of this feather can be seen [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Ostrich_Feather_Badge_of_Henry_IV.svg#mw-jump-to-license), by "Sodacan" on wikicommons.

Can anyone find a photo or even illustration of this image? I can't for the life of me find one. I can find [double ostrich feathers](http://www.mernick.org.uk/seals/other/duchyoflancaster.htm) for the Duchy of Lancaster, just not entwined with *"SOVEREYGNE"*.

I came across this [Seal of John, Duke of Bedford](https://www.stgeorges-windsor.org/conservation-grant-awarded/x-4-1seal/), which looks like it has the ostrich feathers entwined with writing. John of Lancaster was the third son of Henry IV, but I can't find any other higher resolution photos of this to confirm if this is the same symbol

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Erenow site has an image of the seal on it's page titled [The Fears of Henry IV](https://erenow.net/postclassical/the-fears-of-henry-iv-the-life-of-englands-king/22.php), although it isn't particularly high resolution, and doesn't provide further details for the source of the image:

[image: seal impression]

This seems to match the description that you mentioned on p 242 of Charles Boutell's [English Heraldry](http://bridges.rem33.com/books/English_heraldry.PDF)

> "... a very remarkable Seal, used by HENRY IV. a short time before his accession, the shield with helm and crest are placed between two tall Feathers, about each of which is entwined a Garter charged with his favourite and significant Motto the word SOVEREYGNE, ..."

---

I also found the records of two seals in the card index to armorial seals & seal impressions held by the UK National Archives ([QFA 1-25](https://discovery.nationalarchives.gov.uk/details/r/C14505591)). These describe the ostrich feather

> "... *encircled by a scroll lettered ma/so/ve/rey/ne*"

and the cards date the seals to 1394 and 1395.

[image: index card for first seal] (click to enlarge)

[image: index card for second seal] (click to enlarge)

You would probably have to visit in person to view the actual seal impressions.

Comment: It's you again Mr Sempaiscuba! God bless u forever man! You're the best!

Comment: What makes it a “very remarkable” seal?

Comment: @KRyan A good question.  It was the description used by Charles Boutell in his book. Unfortunately, he died in 1877 so we can't ask him exactly what he meant.

Comment: Are you able to discover if the Seal of John, Duke of Bedford, third son of Henry IV also has those Sovereygne feathers entwined?

Comment: @Johan88 [QFA 1-21](https://discovery.nationalarchives.gov.uk/details/r/C14505587) describes two seals of John, Duke of Bedford. The first has "_a shield of arms with helm and crest, a lion, an ostrich feather on the sinister side_". The second has "_a label of five points, with helm [and crest]; on dexter side an eagle and an ostrich feather encircled with ribbon inscribed ? ; field foliaged_". Neither mentions the "Sovereyne" motto, although the 2nd does have an uncertain inscription around the feather.

Comment: @sempaiscuba You are amazing on so many levels. I genuflect to your awesome being, I marvel at your tremendous existence. Thanks again, as ever, forever, Sempaiscuba.

Comment: @sempaiscuba Sovereygne is used plenty in literature, but I can't find any example of it used in heraldry, apart from the claim by Boutell and FoxDavies

Comment: @Johan88 I wouldn't get too hung up about minor differences in spelling.  English spellings were not formalised until much later.

Comment: @sempaiscuba OK. Thanks